# Using Snowflake SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL in a procedure cannot output multiple rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored Procedure to call snowflakes SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL with results from a sql statement assigned to the Body variable passed through. i.e. what is returned from the sql is to be sent in the email body.

However for this email body I want to output 9 columns from a table that has multiple rows, the table is made of various datatype (date, varchar and integers)

The problem I have is this will only work if I return one varchar value from my select statement in the procedure, but I want to select everything in the table and pass that through to the body variable and ultimately email a table with these values

Currently you'll see below im using listAgg and concatenation to return multiple rows in one which is... a real crappy hack and makes for an unattractive email alert

I dont know if what I want to do is possible, if so I suppose I need to do something with the datatypes in the proc and the sql but I am a bit stuck as to what

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SEND_EMAIL(integration_name VARCHAR,email_address_1 
VARCHAR,SUBJECT VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS

$$
DECLARE

  Body VARCHAR;
  SendEmailSQL VARCHAR;

BEGIN

    Body:= (SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT(Clientname, ' - ',Platform, ' ', percentage_diff,  
   '% Difference', '    ||    '))FROM Nick_Alerting.Games_Spins_Degraded);

  SendEmailSQL:= (CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL(:integration_name,:email_address_1, 
:SUBJECT, :Body));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (:SendEmailSQL);

RETURN 'Email Sent Successfully';

END;
$$ ;
```

Thanks in advance,
NY

Comment: As the documentation states, “ Snowflake currently supports only plain text email” - so you are limited to whatever you can construct in a single string

Comment: I have a stored procedure function that will ASCII pretty print a small table, but unfortunately I'm betting the email arrives in proportional font. If the email comes in non-proportional font let me know and I'll hunt down that pretty print function.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately its Calibri